# Ajax call not working until user interaction in IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap and jQuery and I am facing a problem when performing ajax requests on iOS. I do the request , the php on my server receives the information and echo the correct answer. Turns out my app does not 'get' the information until I interact somehow with the screen (scrolling for example) or really wait too long ( over a minute ). This problem evolved, in the beginning happened just after a few requests and now the first ajax already shows it . Another thing I noticed was, when taking out all ( or almost all ) javascript and/or css ( weird ) the problem disappears as if it was something with the phone memory . When doing the request using `async : false` , the problem also disappears! It happens on the iPhone 4 . Was tested on Android and PC (Chrome and Mozilla Firefox ) and it worked fine.

The weirdest thing is that when I interact with the screen , the answer appears, it do not wait a second, it is almost instantaneous ... as if the answer was already there, but not showing up for some reason.

Ps: The error alert don`t appears.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'url',
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {
    data: data
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('error');
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: What is triggering the Ajax call? timeout/interval?

Comment: Just a click event...

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

if you are wanting a funciton to be triggered on response i would use the complete instead of done.

Comment: I`m using done as success, but that is not the problem, when I use success instead the problem remains...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are not cancelling the click action and the page is refreshing

```
$(".yourSelector").on("click",function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   //your ajax call
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn`t work... The fact that when I scroll it works is really driving me nuts...

Comment: do you have any other alternative?